# why run time is considered for complexity analysis and not compile time?

Tags: time-complexity

While analyzing any algorithm we consider its time complexity the root issue i.e. the designer concerns himself primarily with run time and not compile time. 
    It is that whenever we analyze the complexity of some given algorithm we only care about the run time required by the algo and not the compile time. Why is that?

Comment: When is the last time you, as end user of a software product, were satisfied with its terrible runtime performance, just because the programmer didn't have to wait long to compile it?

Comment: That's not to say that compile time is completely ignored. For example, in JIT compilers, compile time of a program *is* a runtime cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilation occurs once. Over the lifetime of a product it therefore has a constant cost. Complexity is a measure of how costs grow proportionally to input. A constant cost does not grow proportionally to input. It therefore contributes zero.

Answer (score 1):

Because, to be blunt, the programmer doesn't really matter. You are designing code for a client and at the end of the day you will compile that code for them. Once it is compiled into a .jar or .exe it shouldn't have to compile again.  They don't care if it took you four hours to compile they only see the run time efficiency. If you only compile once but you run the code 4000 times which is going to matter more. Runtime or compile time?

Answer (score 0):

(N.B. I'm posting late)
Ok, So I see the point why it's pretty obvious.
Simply put "The compilation time doesn't really matter"
All that matters is how fast the program executes on a discreet set of provided input.

Answer (score -1):

compile time may vary programmer to programmer according to their program size for same task but run time only vary according to algorithm, thus run time matters.

Answer (score -1):

because compile time is a function of run time

Comment: What? Are you sure?